# In Android how do you get a reference to a global variable that is a subclass of another global variable?

Tags: java, android

I created a global variable called GlobalVariables in my app:

```
public class GlobalVariables extends Notifications {
     private boolean purchased = false;

     public boolean getPurchaseState() {
         return this.purchased;
     }

     public void setPurchaseState(boolean result) {
         purchased = result;
     }

}
```

As you may have noticed it extends a class called Notifications instead of extending Application. This is because I already had a class called Notifications which itself extends Application, and I read that it's not possible for two classes to extend Application since only one class can be added in the `<application` tag in Manifest, and in my case that class is Notifications. I read that the solution was simply to have one class subclass other, so I had GlobalVariables subclassing Notifications.

So I then wrote this in my activity

```
GlobalVariables globalVariables = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();
```

which causes a crash that says `getApplication()` cannot be cast to `GlobalVariables`.
How do I get globalVariables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, if Notifications is your application class you can't cast it to a subclass as Android still considers it a Notifications class. You could set GlobalVariables as the Application class though (inheriting Notifications).

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve but SharedPreferences might help to access variables across the app and also keep their state when the app gets closed.

Otherwise ViewModels (MVVM) help you access variables across Fragments or different parts of the App, same as Repositories.

Comment: "You could set GlobalVariables as the Application class though (inheriting Notifications)." Hi I don't understand what this means

Comment: I mean you could put GlobalVariables in the Manifest instead of Notifications. 
Because it is a subclass of Notifications, it should have all of the features too

Comment: So I ONLY change the manifest from Notifications to GlobalVariables and then `GlobalVariables globalVariables = (GlobalVariables) getApplication();` will work?

Comment: Also just one more question, Notifications will not be affected in any way?

Comment: I don't see why they would be affected, perhaps you need to move the onCreate method into GlobalVariables but it probably works without that anyways, if it doesn't just call super in the GlobalVariables onCreate